# Webpack stop working after switch to different branch then switch back

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have webpack installed on one of my branch called `"webpack`" while the master branch don't. Everything is working fine at this point.

I had to test something so I switch to `master` branch. While I was in master branch, ran into dependency problem. In order to fix this issue, I deleted `package.json` and `node_modules` in my `master` branch and run `npm install`. Upon fixing the issue, I switch back to my "webpack" branch. Now, I ran into the issue when I run `npm run start`

```
Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'
```

I search on github and apparently it is caused by not have `webpack-cli` install properly. However i did.

My `package.json file` looks like following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": {
    "/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3001"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.4",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
```

It is also weird that everything was working fine before i switch to my master branch.

My question: Why does the error come up suddenly? Does it have to do with the fact that I deleted "node module" in my master? Since they are in different brnach, i don't think they will affect each other.

And how should I fix this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the webpack-dev-server module. Run `npm i -D webpack-dev-server`.

The reason this broke is probably because you had 'webpack-dev-server' in your package.json at one point, but you have recently removed it from your dependencies.

Comment: What is the -D option?

Comment: -D === --save-dev